# ACF get field label in custom code

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, labels

I have some custom code in order to display my custom fields the way I want.

Unfortunately, with this code I can't seem to access the  `$field['label']`. I tried various ways but don't really know how to achieve this.

```
<?php
    $fields = get_fields();
    if( $fields ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
            foreach( $fields as $name => $value ):
                if (stripos($name, 'isbn') !== false) : ?>
                    <li><b><?php echo $name['label']; ?></b> <?php echo $value; ?></li>
                <?php endif;
            endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `$value['label']` and not `$name['label']` ?

Comment: @SallyCJ no, that'S not working either.. It results in: 
"Warning: Illegal string offset 'label' in..."

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($fields);` after `$fields = get_fields();` and check its output. Is there the `label` item?

Comment: @SallyCJ hmm no it's not there! How do I get it?

Comment: Ah I see it now. I thought 'label' was a field. xD Use [`get_field_objects()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_objects/) and not `get_fields()`. =)

Comment: unfortunately when using get_field_objects() It displays only the word "Array" which is not what I want..

Comment: Ok let me try to change the code for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which worked for me:

```
<?php
    $fields = get_field_objects(); // I changed from get_fields()
    if( $fields ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
            // I changed $value to $field (i.e. the variable name)
            foreach( $fields as $name => $field ):
                if (stripos($name, 'isbn') !== false) : ?>
                    <li><b><?php echo $field['label']; ?></b> <?php echo $field['value']; ?></li>
                <?php endif;
            endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

So referring to the `$field` in the code, `$field['label']` is the field label (e.g. "Book ISBN"), and `$field['value']` is the field value. Note though, that the field *value* could be an `array`, so simply `echo`-ing it would (likely throw a PHP warning and) give you a "Array".

See https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_objects/ if you need help with the `get_field_objects()` function.

PS: If you only want to get the label of a single field and not all fields (of the current/target post/user/etc.), you can use [`get_field_object()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/#usage) instead.

Comment: thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for!